# Nested SQL (IN & EXISTS) with group by returns contradictory results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I guess I'm misunderstanding SQL. When I tried the following contradictory query:

```
SELECT id, key, value FROM Things WHERE value > 1 AND key = 'key' AND id IN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM Things 
    WHERE key = 'key' AND value < 1
) GROUP BY id, key, value LIMIT 2;
```

I get the following results:

```
  id    | key        | value
--------+------------+-----------
  92    |         18 |         2
   4    |         18 |         2
```

Similarly, when I try this query:

```
SELECT id, key, value FROM Things a WHERE value > 1 AND key = 'key' AND EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM Things b 
    WHERE a.id = b.id AND a.key = b.key AND b.value < 1
) GROUP BY id, key, value LIMIT 2;
```

I get the same results:

```
  id    | key        | value
--------+------------+-----------
  92    |         18 |         2
   4    |         18 |         2
```

Finally when I try this, I get the correct results:

```
SELECT X.id, X.key, X.value FROM (
    SELECT id, key, value   
    FROM Things   
    WHERE key = 'key' and value < 1
) AS X WHERE X.key = 'key' AND X.value > 1 GROUP BY id, key, value LIMIT 2;

  id    | key        | value
--------+------------+-----------
```

I thought perhaps indexes were messing with me, but I made sure that there are non and it is still behaving like this.

Can somebody explain why this is happening and what it is that I'm misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this query says:

```
SELECT id, key, value FROM Things WHERE value > 1 AND key = 'key' AND id IN (
    SELECT id FROM Things WHERE key = 'key' AND value < 1
) GROUP BY id, key, value LIMIT 2;
```

is, look for all Things with key `key` for which both a row with `value < 1` and a row with `value > 1` exists.  That's not contradictory.

Your second query does the same thing, except it demands that both rows share `id` in addition to `key`.

Your last query looks for a single row with both properties.  That returns an empty set because no value is both smaller than and greater than one.